# TFS 2010 to 2013 Migration, Upgrade and Project Bindings

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, solution, tfs-migration

**The setup:**
My team has chosen the migration method of a TFS 2010 to 2013 upgrade: take DB backups of existing instances (using the TFSBackup tool), copy to new servers, restore to new SQL instances (with TFSRestore tool) and install TFS on new app/build tiers with the 'Upgrade' option.

**Further context:**
I have VS 2010, 2012 and 2013 installed side-by-side on my workstation. I typically don't operate more than one flavor at the same time. And, thus far, I use the same private workspace/mappings in all of them. And depending on what new instance of TFS 2013 upgrade I'm pointing to, the workspace is associated with the correct server value.

**What the...?:**
The current dress rehearsal went relatively smooth. Post-upgrade, we've encountered no issues with opening/manipulating projects, checking-in files, running team builds, etc. Projects act, as before, like they are bound to source control.  However, upon inspecting the *.sln files, the "SccTeamFoundationServer" value is still set to:

`http://<oldServer>:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`

...And yet, it continues to operate as if that didn't matter. In fact, looking in the "Change Source Control" dialog, the bindings look quite correct, pointing to the newer instance...

`http://<newServer>:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`

**Question:**
This is a rather curious state the solution files are in now. Can they continue this way if they stay within TFS? Or would it behoove us to have project owners change their project bindings accordingly? Keep in mind, we're talking nearly 1000 project solutions.

And, of course, if one merely unbinds and rebinds to source control, they're going to get the wrong server value unless they first update the proper SccTeamFoundationServer value in the *.sln file by hand.

Comment: Is the old server still online?  If so, you have to consider that it is still going to it.  Wireshark would tell you for sure.  I'm curious, why rename the server?

Comment: I've recently tried turning off the old TFS instance (TfsServiceControl QUIESCE), and opening projects on the new instance: no problems as long as I'm using the same VS client (newer clients, obviously, want to upgrade certain projects, but that's a separate issue).
And this isn't a server rename; it's a migration and upgrade.

Comment: As a side note, this is why you should always use a specific DNS entry to connect to TFS. You can then change the server or add a load balancer without changing the client configurations.

Comment: Keep in mind that project files can be opened separately from the SLN.  They do not carry the TFS server URL and they work, so the SLN is probably just holding a copy of the value anyways.  If you want to change them all anyways just to be safe, it might be easiest to check out all SLN files across the board, run an external search/replace so you can get them all at once, and check them back in.

Comment: @JohannBlais that's my next goal. Would definitely make the process less painful next time. But we'll probably have one more round of pain just to deal with the DNS change... not sure how to deal with that mid-stream just yet.

Comment: @Brain2000 Yes, we've thought about that. However, most folks are operating through VS. We've discussed the mass-update of sln files, but we're talking nearly 1k. I've discovered that as folks move up VS versions, the project upgrade wizard will modify their sln files to the correct binding URL.  I think we're just going to have to deal with issues as they come.

I appreciate everyone's comments!

Comment: How about setting it up to use friendly DNS names?  See more here:  http://www.edsquared.com/2011/01/03/Using+Friendly+DNS+Names+In+Your+TFS+Environment.aspx

Comment: Thanks @EdBlankenship! We might be a little late for our Control Board in getting this change in for our final migration this week, but, as you said, it's never too late. We'll definitely get this rolling for our TFS dev/sandbox environment.